# WPF animation working erraticaly

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, animation, graphics

I have animation code in MainWindow for a cube which is GeometryModel3D object

**Animation code**

```
  private void animate(GeometryModel3D back)
    {
            Transform3DGroup transGroup = new Transform3DGroup();
           DoubleAnimation cardAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();

            cardAnimation.From = 0;
            cardAnimation.To = 0.3;
            cardAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));

            cardAnimation.AutoReverse = true;                      
            Transform3D transform = new TranslateTransform3D(0, 0, 0);
            transGroup.Children.Add(transform);

            back.Transform = transGroup;
            transform.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform3D.OffsetZProperty,
                      cardAnimation);

    }
```

In **Main window** Code I have

```
   Window1 win1 = new Window1();

   public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

      }

     public void textbox_keydown( KeyEventArgs e)
          {
              if(e.Key==Key.Return)
               {  
                  if( some condition nothing to do with animation at all)
                  { 
                      animate(cube);
                       win1.ShowDialogue();
                    }


                    //Position1 
               }
           }
```

When i run program first time animation does not show and window1 show, now again i put some entry in textbox and enter again second time animation shows and after that every time only first time it does not show.

Also if i put  **"animate(cube);"** at position 1 animation works even first time also and off course every other time too.

Why animation is not working first time when textbox_keydown( KeyEventArgs e) invoked in above case and working only second time and onwards when textbox_keydown( KeyEventArgs e) is invoked.

Is there any threadind problem or initiation i am forgetting ?

Above animation function is in MainWindow after textbox_keydown( KeyEventArgs e) .

Comment: Please post some information about implementation of `win1.ShowDialogue();`, which ma be related to the issue. It's just a guess, but You may also turn off `AutoReverse` property and verify if the animation plays for the first time (or Z offset property is changed as if the animation has played) after `win1` window is closed.

Comment: thanks  that works if i remove Autoreverse property it works but than my animation does not goto original place after cube position changing , i still dont understand problem was autorevers acting too quickly first time animation was called ?
How do i get animation to its place back ?

Comment: Instead of defining `Transform3DGroup` and `TranslateTransform3D` in the c# code (in `animate` method), try to define those in XAML and set a name for `TranslateTransform3D` with `x:Name` property. Then use this name in the `animate` method to begin the animation.

Comment: If this helped, let me know, so I can post it as an answer. This way the solution can be easier found by other people who encounter this issue.

Comment: no it didnt help i just created another function animation which reset animation object  to zero, in a way problem solved

Comment: Ok, I see. Maybe post this information as a solution (or workaround).

Comment: yeah sure you can do that

Comment: I meant that You can post your workaround, so other can find it easily :). You've found it, after all ;).